# Writing a txt file in Python with Apache

Tags: python, apache

Sorry if the title is vague, but what I'm trying to do is create a text file and populate it with whatever the user types in an html form. So far I have a standard form called "pathBox" and I want to save whatever the user types in that box to a text file in the "settings" directory. I have tried the basic:

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

saveToPath = str(form.getvalue('pathBox'))

print ("Path set to: " + saveToPath)

file = open("../settings/pathToSave.txt", "w")
file.write(saveToPath)
file.close()
```

When I run the script in the terminal, it prints out "None" to the text file, which I expect. But when I browse to the python file in my apache server (yes, I configured it correctly - i think) and type a message into the box and press submit, it doesnt create the text file, and I dont know why. Has anybody ever dealt with this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a permissions error. My script was trying to write to a folder that it didn't have write permissions to.